# Threads and java / Server-Client program

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, chat, runnable

I'm trying to build this server client program that enables them to send from one another w/o the restriction of it being a `duplex communication` type. I have tried using interface `Runnable` but I'm a bit confused on how it works should i create 2 `Runnable` interfaces one that receives data and one that sends data so that if I run it in my Main class ill just add them as `Thread`. 
will this make my chat program  run simultaneously??

```
class ServerSend implements Runnable{
//CONSTRUCTOR
 public Server{
//is the constructor really necessary or should I just code in my run() void?
 }

 public void () run{
//
//Where the code should be placed??(Confused)..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement a server-client interface which works in a network I'd use Sockets and connect to a ServerSockets. You would then have a Thread running the client and one running the server accepting new clients.

Answer (score 0):

Just use http://netty.io/
A client-server chat is the most common tutorial